# Log form data for Flask request

Tags: python, logging, flask, python-3.5

I am learning Flask and have trouble reproducing a tutorial. I am using Flask 0.10.1 on Python 3.5.1.

I have the following app, which has a small form on the 'Add' page. I would like to display in the console everything I submit through the form, but I don't get anything except a simple POST message below.

Any help appreciated. Thank you!

[image]

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request
from datetime import datetime
from logging import DEBUG



app = Flask(__name__)
app.logger.setLevel(DEBUG)

bookmarks = []

def store_bookmark(url):
    bookmarks.append(dict (
        url = url,
        user= 'constantin',
        date = datetime.utcnow()
    ))

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html',title='TEST')


@app.route('/add',methods = ['GET','POST'])
def add():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        url = request.form['url']
        store_bookmark(url)
        app.logger.debug('stored url: ')
    return render_template('add.html')


@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return render_template('404.html'),404


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/errorhandling/#error-mails) states:

> If the application runs in production mode (which it will do on your server) you might not see any log messages.

Do you run your code in production or debug mode?

Make sure it is run in [Debug mode](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/quickstart/#debug-mode) by setting the environment variable `FLASK_DEBUG` to true and try again, it should then appear.

Comment: I've set FLASK_DEBUG = 1 before running the server - worked as a charm. Thank you!

Comment: Yes - I was not able to log the data in the form because I didn't enable the debug mode.